# Java naming guide (specific class type naming - not conventions)

Tags: java, syntax, naming

(This has nothing to do with Java conventions)

I'm looking for a guide that can help me understand how to name classes that function in certain ways.

I have looked online and read on various websites about this; but, all I learned is what not to do. i.e lower casing/dashes/dollar-signs.

But what I really want to know is how to name classes like these:

(Looking through similar projects I see that people named it "Module")
In this example, I will be naming them "Function".

```
public class HouseButtonsFunction extends ButtonSwitchFunction{

@Override 
public void interact(Person p, Object...args){
    //if person turns a light switch or open-garage switch
}

}


public class CarButtonsFunction extends ButtonSwitchFunction{

@Override 
public void interact(Person p, Object...args){
    //if person turns on ignition or roof lights
}

}
```

There are also superclasses like

```
PersonInteractionFunction
```

that would deal with things like:

```
PersonWalkingFunction extends PersonInteractionFunction
PersonSittingDownFunction extends PersonInteractionFunction
PersonDrivingFunction extends PersonInteractionFunction
```

So is "Function" the correct word here?

Where can I find out the correct nomenclature?

Comment: What is a "Function" for you? I don't really see what you mean with that.

Comment: I think there is no rule for that. Only the common sense saying "name the thing so you and others can understand what it is"

Comment: You can try this : [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names)

Comment: I'd probably follow the example of the classes in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: Yes but I want it to be universally understood, so I can't go around naming it HouseButtonsWidget or something like that, because it will be misconstrued as a java widget.

Comment: @kay Name your things the way you think it's the clearest. Then if you still think it's a bit confusing, add a comment block to explain what is this class/what does that function. (I recommend you to use Javadoc for this comment block, and to always add them even if you found the naming clear)

Comment: @vincrichaud But obviously some names would be incorrect, i.e "Function" should never be used as it has been above, because it is not technically a "Java Function," it is technically a superclass operator, but naming it "ButtonSwitchSuperClassOperator" and suffixing everything with that would seem kind of inefficient and ugly

Comment: If you know there are a lot of similar projects out there that uses `Module`, I would suggest sticking to that. There is a some chance that people has switched over from other people's API to yours, and it helps them when you don't re-invest the wheel. Also make sure the naming is consistent in your own project.

Comment: @kay Function here does not cause problem because of "Java Function". If your class represent the function of a house button, the naming is okay. As suggested by Andrew, you class here represent more the action of the button, so you shoulkd maybe name it HouseButtonAction, or HouseButtonInteraction

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read the classic an most famous document that was written about naming which is called "Ottinger's Rules for Variable and Class Naming".
It was written by Tim Ottinger back in 1997 and it is still relevant as it was written today.

I would also suggest you to read the books [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) written by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob) and [Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321413091) written by Kent Beck

Comment: Chapter 2 in Clean Code is the updated version of that paper that Bob asked me to write for the anthology. If you can get a copy of each, you'll see some of the evolution (and I won't make a penny from you doing so).

Answer (score 1):

I would use neither "Module" nor "Function" here.

"Module" is associated with a storage. For instance, it can be a class that holds a collection or gathers information about classes that can be logically grouped together.

"Function" is a means to transform something into something else. For example, a `Function<Person, Rabbit>` turns a human into a rabbit.

I would go with the word "Action" since you defined a single method `interact`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule/conventions about how to name your class and methods. You have to follow the common sense : **Name things explicitly so you and others can understand what it is and what it does**

As example, for the case of a button in a house, with a function that interact this button. You can think of different valid naming. The class could be named `HouseButtonFunction` or `HouseButtonAction`, etc. And the method could be named `interact()` or `action()`, etc. The difference depend on what does exactly your method. If it toggles something, use `toggle()`. **Use the one you find the most understandable and the most explicit.** In your case, personnaly, since your class define the interaction of this button, I would suggest to name it `HouseButtonInteraction`

In all the case, I strongly recommend to comment your stuff so there is no more possible confusion.

```
/**
 * This method is called when a person interact with the House button.
 * This method will action the given object
 * @param p : the person that interact with the house button
 * @param o : the object to action
 */
public void interact(Person p, Object o) { ... }
```

Also try to always be consistent in your naming. i.e. If for the house button you name the class `HouseButtonFunction` and the method `interact`. Do not change the naming for the car button :

```
//not to do !!
class : CarButtonAction
method : actionObject()
//To do
class : CarButtonFunction
method : interact()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the name of the class should be a noun which is specific and is easy to understand to someone reading the code. Ending the class name with 'Function' is fine considering the super class seems to be named `Function` as well. But if you can rename the super class i would name them ending with `Handler`. Like

- PersonWalkingHandler
- PersonSittingDownHandler
- PersonDrivingHandler

etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard rule as many stated in comments. Naming convention is a best practice so when all developers follow a certain naming standard then they can easily correlate and understand code effectively, otherwise it's cumbersome task to build relation.

In general practice a Class should be referred to Noun where as methods refer to action so those are associated with verbs.

In above case, I would suggest something like this..

> HouseButtonsFunction => House or HouseBotton
>
> ButtonSwitchFunction => Switch or SwitchBotton
>
> CarButtonsFunction   => CarButton
>
> PersonWalkingFunction          => Walker
>
> PersonSittingDownFunction      => Sitter
>
> PersonDrivingFunction          =>  Driver etc..

Note that it all depends on naming convention you follow..